# Como visualizo propriedades de botões em VBA de uma planilha excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, propriedade, controles

Tenho uma planilha com botões que ocultam e reexibem campos conforme o conjunto de dados preenchidos.
Quando tento ver ou alterar as propriedades dos controles, não consigo. O VBA só mostra as propriedades da planilha.

Comment: Qual é versão do excel que você esta usando? só assim poderemos responder com certeza

Answer (score 0):

Há 2 tipos de botões para serem colocados diretamente na planilha. Para ambos vc acessa as propriedades clicando com o botão direito sobre eles.

[image: Inserir Controle]

Para o botão de *Controle de Formulário*, vc acessa as propriedades acessando a janela na opção "Formatar Controle...":

[image: Controle de Formulário]

Para o botão de *Controle Activex*, o "Formatar Controle..." tem pouquíssimas opções, mas vc pode acessar a janela de propriedades completas selecionando "Propriedades" com o menu contextual, ao clicar com o botão direito sobre o controle. Activex é o tipo de controle com propriedades semelhantes aos controles de UserForm, em VBA:

[image: Controle Activex]

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema está meio confuso, mas se vc está tentando achar o código que um botão roda, talvez ele tenha sido associado a um evento específico sobre aquele botão/controle. Então talvez o que vc esteja procurando é uma `Sub` presente num módulo de planilha, e não no módulo simples:

[image: Módulo de Planilha com evento de controles]

Comment: Desculpa se não me fiz claro. Na verdade, o código e a função do botão não vem ao caso. Independente da função, o que eu quero é acessar as propriedades do controle (nome, cor, visibilidade, etc.).Mesmo em modo de Design e com o Botão em edição, quando clico no ícone Propriedades, só me mostra as propriedades da planilha. Do botão, o máximo que eu consigo editar é o texto. Meu Excel é o 2010.

Comment: Vc deve estar usando um botão de formulário, então, em vez de um botão Activex!